# Open PHP file using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am trying to execute a PHP file using AJAX, which is supposed to update a txt file

here is my javascript

```
    function getXMLHttp()
    {
      var xmlHttp

  try
  {
    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    //Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}



function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  var host = window.location.hostname;
  var dir1=window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
  var dir2=window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  var p = document.getElementById(\'CTI_IP\').value;
  var url=\'http://\'+host+\'/\'+dir1+\'/modules/company/include/file.php?var=\'+p;
  xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) 
 {
  xmlHttp.send();
 }
}
```

the url is fine, i alerted it, copy pasted the link, the php file is working perfect and updating the txt file but it won't work in ajax? why

thanks !!

Comment: Same origin policy issue may be. Is the domain of the url being access is same as the domain of the caller page?

Comment: He will need to fix the blatant misuse of escaping quotes before he can find out if that is an issue.

Comment: You need to include where you call `MakeRequest()`.

Comment: <input type='submit' onclick='MakeRequest();'/>

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
var p = document.getElementById(\'CTI_IP\').value;
                                ^HERE
```

(And similar ones scattered throughout).

This should have shown up in your browser's JavaScript error console.

Comment: I'd recommend JSLint (http://www.jslint.com). Since your editor does not seem to check for syntax errors, invalid characters and such, I'd highly encourage using this tool. It helps maintaining clean, functioning JavaScript. Depending on the coding environment you use, it's also integratable. My vim showed 3 (possible) errors right away when i pasted your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the URL, you are building it wrong. You are escaping quotes that don't need escaping. It should be built as follows:

```
var url = "http://" + host + "/" + dir1 + "/modules/company/include/file.php?var=" + p;
```

You are also escaping the quotes on your getElementById call for some unknown reason. It should be called as follows:

```
var p = document.getElementById("CTI_IP").value;
```

The only time you want to escape quotes is when you want them included in your string. In these instances, you shouldn't have escaped them because they denote a string - they aren't meant to be included.

I recommend that you research a little bit about how strings work in Javascript.

Once you've fixed those errors, remove the if block around your `xmlHttp.send()`.

You have:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) 
{
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

But should only have

```
xmlHttp.send();
```

Finally, since you don't include it in your example above, I'm assuming you aren't actually making a call to your `MakeRequest()` function anywhere. You have to call that function somewhere in your code to get it to actually execute the function.

Simply invoke the function as follows:

```
MakeRequest();
```

Comment: he URL and p are both correct I check them using alert, they are both correct

Comment: No. They are absolutely not correct. In fact, you have an unterminated string constant, which is a huge problem.

Comment: Where do you call `MakeRequest()`?

Comment: in the body <input type='button' onclick='MakeRequest();'/>

Comment: i removed the if condition its now   xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send(); but still not work

Comment: It worked for me, using your code, and the edits contained in my post, so I don't know what else to tell you. You must have an error somewhere. Check your Javascript debug console.

Comment: How can check if the .open is actually reaching and opening the .php file ?

Comment: You would have to use the onreadystatechanged event handler to capture any output that was sent from your PHP script.

Comment: No, it's not. It's 1 up until you call send(). At which point it becomes 2. You then need to assign a function to onreadystatechange to handle what happens when the state changes. If you don't do that, then you will not know when the state changes. In that function, you will check for the readyState == 4, and then you will be able to get your data.

Comment: var url = "http://" + host + "/" + dir1 + "/modules/company/include/file.php?var=" + p;
  //alert(url);
  xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
  xmlHttp.send();
  what do i need to add after these ?

Comment: I don't need to capture output from PHP, i just need to run it, the PHP script will update a txt file.

Comment: The idea was for you to get the output of the PHP file so that you would know it was running. I think this is hopelessly beyond your skill level. Employ someone to write your code - this is ridiculous.